# Get distinct column value from a specific value ignoring value from other retrieved column - mysql

Tags: mysql

I am running a query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(length(unit_number)) as strlen, unit_number FROM `units` where building_id > 783 and building_id < 793
```

and it returns data like:

```
strlen | unit_number
    6  |  A.1001
    6  |  A.1002
    6  |  A.1003
    7  |  A.10001
    7  |  A.10002
    8  |  A.100001
    8  |  A.100002
```

However, I don't want this strlen column to have a duplicate value. I want something like:

```
strlen | unit_number
    6  |  A.1001
    7  |  A.10001
    8  |  A.100001
```

I don't mind if it picks the first row from their type or from last. I just want to make sure that strlen column has unique value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER` we can try:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LENGTH(unit_number) ORDER BY unit_number) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT LENGTH(unit_number) AS strlen, unit_number
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL which do not support `ROW_NUMBER`, we can try:

```
SELECT distinct LENGTH(t1.unit_number) AS strlen, t1.unit_number
FROM units t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT LENGTH(unit_number) AS strlen, MIN(unit_number) AS min_unit_number
    FROM units where building_id > 783 and building_id < 793
    GROUP BY strlen
) t2
    ON LENGTH(t1.unit_number) = t2.strlen AND t1.unit_number = t2.min_unit_number;
```

Comment: Unrecognized statement type. (near "WITH" at position 0) using MySQL 8.0.1 and trying to run query via phpmyadmin

Comment: Unknown column 'strlen' in 'field list' I was using `length(unit_number) as strlen`

Comment: I run `SELECT LENGTH(t1.unit_number) AS strlen, t1.unit_number
FROM units t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT LENGTH(unit_number) AS strlen, MIN(unit_number) AS min_unit_number
    FROM units
    where building_id > 783 and building_id < 793
    GROUP BY strlen
) t2
    ON LENGTH(t1.unit_number) = t2.strlen AND t1.unit_number = t2.min_unit_number` but still returning duplicated one

Comment: with just these data sets it seems working but on my real db is not working fine. It is duplicating if it has more than one row with same unit_number

Comment: looks like adding distinct on select fix the issue.

Comment: BTW, isn't it possible without subquery?